# Drupal Views - How to return information about a view that is being rendered

Tags: drupal, view

I'm having trouble dealing with hooks for the Views module in Drupal. What I'm trying to do is determine which view is being rendered so that I can identify it and make changes to it. IOW, I don't know ahead of time which view I'm working on.

In the code below, I've replaced my actual module name with "MODULENAME".

In my .module file I have included a file MODULENAME.views.inc file with the following:

```
    include_once ( dirname(__FILE__) . '/MODULENAME.views.inc');
```

In the .views.inc file, I have a MODULENAME_views_api function like this:

```
    function MODULENAME_views_api() {
      return array('api' => 2, 'path'=> drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME'),
      );
    }
```

Those seem to work just fine. So, now I try to get down to business with an actual hook...

```
    function MODULENAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
      $get_view_info = $view->name;
      echo $get_view_info;
    }

    MODULENAME_views_pre_render();
```

The problem is this throws an error, "Missing argument 1 for MODULENAME_views_pre_render().

So, obviously it expects me to pass in an identifier of some sort to tell it which view I want. But that's the whole point of this function is to determine which view is being rendered. If I knew the answer to that, then I wouldn't need to call the function in the first place.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a function call that I can use to return this identifier?

Comment: To be more clear, what I'm asking is if there is a way to get an array of all the parameters of a view that has been requested? As in, the ID of the view, the parameters, the display info, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hook into things by **implementing** hooks, so this part of your code is ok:

```
<?php
function MODULENAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  $get_view_info = $view->name;
  echo $get_view_info;
}
```

But this:

```
<?php
MODULENAME_views_pre_render();
```

Why? You're not generating a view, [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) is. It's not your job to invoke the hook. You just implement it.

So, you need to make changes to the view? you do it right there:

```
<?php
function MODULENAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'TheViewIWantToModify') {
      // Make some changes to the $view
  }
}
```

And that's it.

Also, note that depending on the type of modifications you want to do, you *might* want to implement another hook instead of hook_views_pre_render(). Take a look at the *docs/docs.php* file that comes with Views (version 6.x-2.12 at least, I don't know which version you have, and BTW you should indicate this) and starting on like 538 you'll see a few `hook_views_pre_` and `hook_views_post_` type of hooks (that is, their descriptions, for you to know what each of them are good for), and then you can decide which one to implement in your module.

Comment: Alexander, thank you for your detailed response. However, I'm still in the woods on it. I'm using Views 3 on D7. The issue is that I want to implement a function whenever a view is rendered; regardless of which one it is. IOW, I don't know in advance which view it is. So, I think the reason I'm having problems is that these hooks expect me to be loading a $view object as a parameter into the function. So I think I need a way of firing that off whenever a view is created so that I can pass that object into these functions, right?

Comment: I think I'm looking for something like hook_init(), but for views. So it is something where each time a view is created, it fires off this function where I can grab the ID for the view and it's parameters to use in my module.

Comment: Ok, Alexander, after two days of playing with it, a lightbulb finally lit up for me on it. The &$view is a reference and the function is automatically called. So I don't have to explicitly call it. Instead I run this (or any other) function and the variables are set at that point. Thanks for your help.